# module 'tkintermapview' not found error in python

Tags: python, import, module, resolve, tkintermapview

I have this:   module 'tkintermapview' not found error in python. I'm using Python 3.11 version. Pls help me on this. Have been trying for a day.

I'm totally zero beginner in Python. I tried to import this module in MS store.

Comment: You might need to edit your code, but you did not post any code, hard to say for sure, much less how it would need to change.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's tkintermapview is this package on [github](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/TkinterMapView) or on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tkintermapview/).

If you install Python from MS store, you get plain Python with everything [described in the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) and not external packages.

If you want to use external packages, you should check before the [virtual env](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and pip usage with [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

It will allow you to install `tkintermapview` for your project.